# Why are the nodes (or neurons) in neural networks depicted as circles?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, hidden-layers

Why are the nodes (or neurons) in neural networks depicted as circles?

What is the difference between a circle and a box in diagrams of neural networks?

Comment: There is no fully standardised representation of neural network architecture. It will depend on where you have seen this. Some writers might want to show a key difference by changing the shape of the node. Others will not care and will just show circles or boxes for everything. Could you please show an example of where you have seen this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is that we call them nodes and nodes are usually depicted using circles in graph theory. We model them as graphs for both forward and backward paths.